# blend overlapping triangles in opengl

Tags: ios, opengl-es, alphablending

I'm building a thick line from triangles. The problem i'm having is that when the curve is semi transparent and some triangles overlap i get the effect in the picture. I would like for the triangles alphas to not get added.

I'm using this blend function:

```
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_CONSTANT_ALPHA, GL_CONSTANT_ALPHA);
```

[image: what i see]

Answer (score 1):

You may render the curve to separate render target with full opacity and then draw that target with custom alpha. Otherwise you should avoid overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

you can use stencil test for blocking the drawing of already drawn fragments (which prevent blending from the first place)